# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'Symbol(StrapiCustomCoreController)' migrating strapi to typescript

Tags: typescript, strapi

I'm migrating my strapi project to typescript. I've installed all strapi packages to version `4.15.5` and renamed files to ts. However when running `strapi develop` I get the following error:

```
[2024-01-03 10:50:48.102] debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2024-01-03 10:50:48.103] error: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'Symbol(StrapiCustomCoreController)' in undefined
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'Symbol(StrapiCustomCoreController)' in undefined
    at isCustomController (/home/dev/gn/strapi-cms/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/factories.js:80:35)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at Strapi.sendStartupTelemetry (/home/dev/gn/strapi-cms/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/Strapi.js:243:68)
    at Strapi.postListen (/home/dev/gn/strapi-cms/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/Strapi.js:266:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Server.onListen (/home/dev/gn/strapi-cms/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/Strapi.js:276:11)
```

The error appears in strapi's controller factories module `node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/factories.js` in this method:

```js
const isCustomController = (controller) => {
  return symbols.CustomController in controller; // controller is undefined!?
};
```

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

**[SOLVED]**

The issue was indeed strapi running into an undefined controller. That's because within the controller folder I had helper modules utils/constants. Moving these files outside the controller folder solved the issue.

```
deleted:    src/api/metric/controllers/constants.ts
created:    src/api/metric/utils/constants.ts
```

My current file tree

```
src/api/metric
├── content-types
│   └── metric
│       ├── cookie.ts
│       ├── lifecycles.ts
│       ├── schema.json
│       └── utils.ts
├── controllers
│   └── metric.ts
├── routes
│   └── metric.ts
├── services
│   └── metric.ts
└── utils
    ├── constants.ts
    ├── index.ts
    └── types.ts
```